Changing the layout of the standard button for the custom object
there is a change owner button standardized by salesforce. They want to add another checkbox on the layout of this button. How can I add this field to the layout of this button? Note that It shouldn't take me to new url. Add only the checkbox on the change owner button.


There is no way to  Override this features in salesforce Lighting.
Reference Article:
1)https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWdWUAV/allow-change-owner-button-to-be-overriden
2)https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4RHiSAN#:~:text=No%2C%20you%20can%27t%20override,with%20your%20own%20Visualforce%20page.
Workaround Solution:

Need to create Custom Components like LWC, Aura or Screen Flow. Which is feasible.

